# Alternative to Having and Group By

Tags: mysql

I'm in the DB classes, and I have to understand and show that it is possible to get the results of **`HAVING`** and **`GROUP BY`** without using themselves. I searched for alternatives for those 2 commands, but I didn't understand anything.

Can someone give me examples?

Comment: Are there are other restrictions? Is `DISTINCT` allowed?

Comment: No! I just want to use different queries that shows that are possible to have tge same results of GROUP BY, using a different approach.. And the same with HAVING

Comment: I'm not sure that it is possible but ok.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a query like:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*)
FROM T
GROUP BY category
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
```

You can mimic that with:

```
SELECT category, cnt
FROM (
    SELECT x.category
       , ( SELECT COUNT(*) from T where T.category = x.category ) as cnt
    FROM (
        SELECT distinct category from T -- GROUP BY
    ) as x
) as y
WHERE y.cnt > 3 -- HAVING
```

Answer (score 0):

Implicit `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE grp='first' THEN val END) SumOfFirst
     , SUM(CASE grp='second' THEN val END) SumOfSecond
     , MAX(CASE WHEN grp IN ('first','second') THEN val END) MaxInFirstAndSecond
FROM table;
```

Implicit `HAVING`? Implicit both `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` in one query? I cannot come up...

Comment: Not in one query, I need in different queries. You can use different approaches for each.

Comment: Another question, is your code in pure SQL?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos "pure SQL" What do You mean? T-SQL? SQL-2011 std? etc.? Regardless I don't know, theory is not interesting for me... sorry.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos the code in the answer is standard SQL. It uses basic SQL (SELECT, FROM, IN, CASE, SUM, MAX)

Comment: @Akina - use a CTE or subquery.  Add a `WITH` clause on the outside to simulate a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @MichaelKutz please post an answer ;)

Comment: @MichaelKutz You mean implicit `HAVING` with explicit `GROUP BY` only, is it?

Comment: @Vérace Check the authors of that phrases...

Comment: @Vérace Of course. "`in the DB classes`" (c) by topicstarter, "`theory is not interesting for me`" is my phrase.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you write a small program for the purpose. For example, suppose you don't want to run this:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) FROM product GROUP BY category;
```

First, you will need to know which categories exist:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM product;
```

Then, for each category, you get the number of products:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product WHERE category = 'something';
```

To emulate a `HAVING` condition, you can filter out the results in your program. You cannot do that in `WHERE`.

Of course in the real world you will never have to do something like this.